# Map input to a possible output based on past data

Tags: database, algorithm, mapping, recommendation-engine

I need to implement a feature that receives a bunch of variables and based on past data that will be stored in a DB I need to output a possible output.

So basically I need to create a DB to store the past data (let's say the vector of inputs (x, y, z) was mapped to 'w' and this will be stored in the DB).
If in the future I receive the vector (x, y, z) I know that based on the DB it should output 'w'.

The flow should be like this:

1. Go over past data and save each possible vector of inputs to their related output in a DB.
2. Receive inputs in the future that do not have an output, and based on the DB, output a possbile answer.

I've never done something like this before, and would be glad to hear possible solutions.
Is there a recommended DB for such task?

- AI solutions are not preferred although I think it might ease up the process.

Thanks in advance!

Searching Google but still didn't find something useful

Answer (score 0):

All of your point represent a function in the space? the same function?

If so, you can re-generetae the function of these variable from some points in DB and then apply it on your input.

Comment: Sort of yes. Your answer is very high level, do you have something more specific?
We should take in consideration that every now and then there may be an unkown input and we should guess the answer based on what we have in the DB

Comment: Yes, assume we talk about a line in 2D, for example: y=2x+5.
If your inputs are:
0 => 5
1 => 7
2 => 9

And now you got as input 3 - because all of points are on the same line, you can extract two points from DB and got the slope, and use one point to get the equation of line, and use it with x=3 and find your output.

For our example, the input is 3, and I don't have data about 3.
I extract two points (0,5) and (1,7) then m=(7-5)/(1-0)=2.
Now - 
y-5=2(x-0):
y = 2x+5
And I set x=3, so y=2*3+5 = 11, and it is my result.
NOTE: All of this just if all of your points on same function